# SMTP Client Exception

Tags: .net, smtp, smtpclient

NET SMTPClient class

```
  try
        {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

I am getting the following exception

```
Message "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for doglin@gmail.com"  string


at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at MarilynDenisServices.Core.Services.EmailSender.SendEmail(IEmailModel model) in d:\dev\MarilynDenisServices\src\Core\Services\EmailSender.cs:line 42
```

I have put the SMTP setting in web.config already.

```
<mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="192.168.16.200" />
                <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\TEMP" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
```

ip is legitimate. Why am I still getting this error? Any ideas? Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a security or permission related error because the SMTP will not send out emails when the request comes from an untrusted resource.

Kindly contact the SMTP administrator and provide authentication (probably a userid and password) to connect to the SMTP server.  This will resolve the issue and the server will be able to send out emails as expected.